# Change Active Slick Carousel using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

We are using the [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) such that we have the `<div class='item__wrapper'>` only displaying 1 slide at a time. Below it are three `items` where on click of the `item`, the slick carousel should be updated.

**Problems**

1. When using `item__boxes` as a `slick` carousel, all of our styling is messed up so we cannot do `$('.item__boxes).slick({});`
2. When clicking on the first, second, or third `item` in `item__boxes`, the `item__wrapper` is always set to `slide 3`

**Question**

- How can we setup the `item__boxes` such that on click of that `item` it matches our goals? For example, clicking on second `item` in `item__boxes` sets the `item__wrapper` to second slide.

**Goal/Expected Results:**

1. On click of first `item`, set the first slide as the active slide in `item__wrapper`
2. on click of second `item`, set the second slide as the active slide in `item__wrapper`
3. on click of third `item`, set the third slide as the active slide in `item__wrapper`
4. do all of the goals `1-3` without doing `$('.item__boxes).slick({});`

**Code:**

```js
$('.item__wrapper').slick({
 
          infinite: true,
          speed: 1500,
          dots: false,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false
});

$('.item__boxes').on('click', function() {
 
 var slickIndex = $(this).attr('data-slick-index');
 $('.item__wrapper').slick('slickGoTo', slickIndex);
});
```

```css
.filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 45px;
  margin-right: -45px;
}
.item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.item.active {
  display: block;
}
.item1 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature");
}
.item2 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
}
.item3 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
}
.item__wrapper {
  max-width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
}
.item__img img {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.item__text {
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-right: 70px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item__boxes {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.item__boxes > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.col-padding {
  padding: 16px 16px 5px 16px;
}
.col-m-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-t-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="item__wrapper">
   <div class="item active" id='item1'>
     <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 1</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   <div class="item active" id="item2" >
        <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 2</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   <div class="item active"  id="item3" >
        <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 3</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
 
   
</div>
<div class="item__boxes">
     <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slick-index="-1">
      <div>Some Title</div>
      <div>Enthusiastically incubate diverse initiatives without multifunctional strategic theme areas.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slick-index="0">
     <div>Globally Title</div>
     <div>Globally impact integrated infomediaries via seamless mindshare. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slick-index="1">
     <div>Distinctively Title</div>
     <div>Distinctively strategize long-term high-impact ideas whereas client-centered leadership skills.</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$('.item__wrapper').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1500,
  dots: false,
  prevArrow: false,
  nextArrow: false
});

$('[data-slide]').click(function(e){
  var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
  $('.item__wrapper').slick('slickGoTo', slideno);
});
```

```css
.filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 45px;
  margin-right: -45px;
}
.item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.item.active {
  display: block;
}
.item1 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature");
}
.item2 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
}
.item3 {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
}
.item__wrapper {
  max-width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
}
.item__img img {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.item__text {
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-right: 70px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item__boxes {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.item__boxes > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.col-padding {
  padding: 16px 16px 5px 16px;
}
.col-m-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-t-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="item__wrapper">
   <div class="item active" id='item1'>
     <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 1</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   <div class="item" id="item2" >
        <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 2</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   <div class="item"  id="item3" >
        <div class="item__text">
      <div class="filter">
       <h3>Some title 3</h3>
       <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. Compellingly scale future-proof content rather than enterprise users. Uniquely build scalable applications vis-a-vis performance based functionalities. Monotonectally procrastinate.</p>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
 
   
</div>
<div class="item__boxes">
     <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slide="0">
      <div>Some Title</div>
      <div>Enthusiastically incubate diverse initiatives without multifunctional strategic theme areas.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slide="1">
     <div>Globally Title</div>
     <div>Globally impact integrated infomediaries via seamless mindshare. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding" data-slide="2">
     <div>Distinctively Title</div>
     <div>Distinctively strategize long-term high-impact ideas whereas client-centered leadership skills.</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: that was silly of me, I see the issue. in my initial JS, I mistakenly used the `item__boxes` when i should have been using the individual `<div class="box col-m-12 col-t-6 col-padding">` elements.