# Is it possible on slick carousel to set the slick-current to be the first item on each pages

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

Let's say I have 4 pages, by default the **"MAIN"** text is the first item inside the slick and it is active. What I want to happen is when I click the **"PAGE 1 HTML"** or any other page links inside that slick. That text links will now be the first item and it is active on page load.

Is it possible to be dynamically added on my `script.js` rather than set the slickGoTo/initialSlide on each pages to target the current page. I'm not sure if the events `selector.on('click')` then trigger the `slickGoto` will help.

Below is my **partial** code and also here is the **complete** sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/slick-active-on-page-dk5der).

See also my images example below.

```js
/*script.js*/
$(function () {
  $(".slick-category--lists").slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

```css
/*styles.js*/
.slick-next,
.slick-prev {
  background: blue;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.slick-next {
  right: 0;
}

.slick-category--lists {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.slick-current a {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="slick-category--lists">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="fw-bold">MAIN</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.html" class="fw-bold">PAGE 1 HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html" class="fw-bold">PAGE 2 HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html" class="fw-bold">PAGE 3 HTML</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="padding: 50px;">MAIN content...</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the main page.**

[image]

**Other pages should be like this, pages text links inside slick will be the first item on page load and active.**

[image]

**Updates:**
Codesandbox have been updated and I just put `slickGoTo` methods on each page to achieve what I want. But I'm still looking for the possibilities to achieve it dynamically on `script.js`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Active Slick Carousel using div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772406/change-active-slick-carousel-using-div)

Comment: I don't think so, because what I want is when I click each of the links inside the slick it will go to each separates pages and the slick item of that link should be the first item in the slick and it is active. I'm trying to do it using on click events, then trigger the slickGoto, but no to avail. I have updated the above question.

Comment: You'll have to fetch the current page, write an if based on which page you are at and determine the correct slide and then use the `slickGoto`

Comment: any idea how to do that? you can fork my codepen if you want. thanks!